# Sonarqube: Is it possible to adapt duplication metric for javascript code?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, duplication, metric

At the moment the duplication metric for JavaScript Code in SonarQube code is defined as followed: 
**“There should be at least 100 successive and duplicated tokens.
Those tokens should be spread at least on 10 lines of code.”**

Is there a way to change the nummer of tokens and the number of lines? Since I want to have 5 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should put this line in your sonar-project.properties file.

```
sonar.cpd.js.minimumLines=5
```

See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Duplications:

> A piece of code is considered as duplicated as soon as there are at
>   least 100 successive and duplicated tokens (can be overridden with
>   property sonar.cpd.${language}.minimumTokens) spread on at least 10
>   lines of code (can be overridden with property
>   sonar.cpd.${language}.minimumLines)

Comment: The sonarqube link added in the answer is asking for user name and password.Please check.